# Unable to write multiple fields in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to fetch some fields from a webpage and write those fields in a text file. When I write data in a csv file or excel, I can do them in the right way. However, in case of writing data in a text file, I get stuck.

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
for item in soup.select(".question-summary"):
    name = item.select_one(".user-details a").text.strip()
    title = item.select_one(".question-hyperlink").text.strip()
    views = item.select_one(".views").text.strip()
    print(name,title,views)
```

***How can I write the scraped fields in a text file keeping three spaces gap between them?***

Comment: This code doesn't write to a file at all. Please show the actual code where the problem occurs.

Comment: why parsing webpage with `lxml` ?

Comment: What do you mean by actual code @mkrieger1? Do you wanna see how I wrote them in a csv file?

Comment: The code where you tried to write something to a text file, but the result was not as you had expected.

Comment: Do you suggest `html.parser` instead of `lxml` or any other means @RomanPerekhrest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.format`.

**Ex:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

with open("your.txt", "w") as outfile:                #Open file for write
    for item in soup.select(".question-summary"):
        name = item.select_one(".user-details a").text.strip()
        title = item.select_one(".question-hyperlink").text.strip()
        views = item.select_one(".views").text.strip()
        print(name,title,views)
        outfile.write("{}   {}   {}".format(name,title,views))   #Write Data with 3 space.
```

Comment: I tried your suggested appraoch but the thing is all the data are being written in a single row @Rakesh. If there are thirty names then I should get thirty individual rows. The bottom line is: the data should be written in a newline in each iteration. Thanks.

Comment: `outfile.write("{}   {}   {}\n".format(name,title,views))`